# Overlay a PNG image (made in photoshop with transparency) on to a JPG using PHP

Tags: php, image, image-processing

I have two images. I need to place one png image with some transparent layers on a jpeg.

This code SAVES the image in the dir as "merged.png" instead of showing it -

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: image/png");
$width = 200;
$height = 200;

$base_image = imagecreatefromjpeg("image.jpg");
$top_image = imagecreatefrompng("miod.png");
$merged_image = "merged.png";

imagesavealpha($top_image, true);
imagealphablending($top_image, true);

imagecopy($base_image, $top_image, 100, 100, 100, 100, $width, $height);
imagepng($base_image, $merged_image);
?>
```

-How do I display it on the page itself?

Comment: just a try: did you try to set `imagealphablending` for `$base_image` too?

Comment: What happens if you just do `imagepng($base_image);`? The second parameter to imagepng is a file to save to; without parameters it outputs directly.

Comment: It worked :) Gracias!

Comment: Cool. I've posted my guess as an answer now we know it was right :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`imagepng`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php) has two main modes of operation. With a single parameter, it outputs the file directly, so it'll show up in the browser. With two parameters, as you have, it wills save the image from the first parameter into the file given in the second parameter.

So -- just drop your second parameter, and things should work fine:

```
 imagepng($base_image);
```